# posgresql error: /usr/bin/chcon : can't apply partial context to unlabeled file

Tags: linux, fedora, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out why my posgresql is failing to start on startup.. I manually run this at the terminal

```
# chkconfig postgresql on 
# service postgresql start 
/usr/bin/chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabelled file /var/lib/pgsql/pgstartup.log 
Initalizing database:           [  OK  ]  
Starting postgresql service:    [  OK  ]
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you include the output of running the command "ls -Z /var/lib/pgsql/pgstartup.log"?

Comment: Also, this might be helpful: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=145359

Answer (score 1):

It looks like /var/lib/pgsql/pgstartup.log does not have an SELinux label so SELinux is preventing postgres from accessing it. See [this page](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/selinux-user-guide/f10/en-US/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html) for more info on SELinux labels.